# Error in install conda-forge featuretools

Tags: conda, featuretools

I have one question in install featuretools by conda-forge.

After following command

```
conda install -c conda-forge featuretools
```

I got these errors.

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with a past
explicit spec that is not an explicit spec in this operation (s3fs):

  - featuretools -> s3fs[version='>=0.1.5']
  - featuretools -> tqdm[version='>=4.19.2']

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

  - anaconda -> alabaster==0.7.12=py36_0
  - anaconda -> anaconda-client==1.7.2=py36_0
  - anaconda -> anaconda-navigator==1.6.9=py36h11ddaaa_0
  - anaconda -> anaconda-project==0.8.2=py36_0
  - anaconda -> asn1crypto==0.24.0=py36_0
...
```

I could not understand the following error message:

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be
>   incompatible with a past explicit spec that is not an explicit spec in
>   this operation.

Since my tqdm's version is higher than requirement and I just install and updated s3fs.

```
:~> tqdm -v
4.32.2
```